# How to create a filter in views which only shows contents that current user can edit?

Tags: views, users

I set content access permission using nodeaccess_userreference module, I need a view to shows contents that user can change.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a very well-elaborated patch/module but it might solve your problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/620392 I've just found it...